# Mysql how to set best indexes for my query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please check my query and suggest me indexing value and how can I decide which columns will be in indexes. Query is very slow when where clause exist otherwise query is just fine. Offset value is also slow down query.

```
SELECT
            attachment.attachment_id AS attachmentID,
            attachment.data_item_id AS candidateID,
            attachment.title AS title,
            candidate.first_name AS firstName,
            candidate.last_name AS lastName,
            candidate.city AS city,
            candidate.state AS state
           
           
        FROM
            attachment
        LEFT JOIN candidate
            ON attachment.data_item_id = candidate.candidate_id
        
       where candidate.is_active = 1
           
        ORDER BY
            lastName ASC
        LIMIT 92000, 20
```

Comment: edit your question to show output of (as text) `show create table yourtablename` (for each table used in the query) and `explain SELECT ...rest of your query`, please

Comment: While bearing in mind GL's observations regarding the redundant outer join, take a look at Quassnoi's excellent (if somewhat dated) article on late row lookups: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: The query is malformed. The predicate `candidate.is_active = 1` defeats the outer join, and make it work efectively as an inner join. Please fix the query, first.

Comment: First, explain why you need `OFFSET 92000` and what type of list will be that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is basically:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM attachment a JOIN
     candidate c
     ON a.data_item_id = c.candidate_id
WHERE c.is_active = 1
ORDER BY c.last_name ASC
LIMIT 92000, 20;
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` anyway, so there is no reason to use `LEFT JOIN`.

I would recommend the following indexes:

- `candidate(is_active, candidate_id, last_name)`
- `attachment(data_item_id)`

You could expand the indexes to include all columns being selected.

Note that offsetting 92,000 rows takes a bit of effort so the query will never be lightning fast.

Comment: curious about if first index would really suffice for the order by, sql-server at least, does a costly sorting operation, solved only by adding candidate(last_name,candidate_id). Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Teson . . . I would expect it to work but you would need to test it on your system to see if it worked.

Comment: I move where clause into join then query much faster (taking 8 sec) so speed will improve like 2sec ?

Comment: @AshishNishad . . . I don't understand your comment.  Moving the `where` condition to the `on` clause would generate a different result set.